# Change color only the selected option but not all options in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic drop down lists coming from back end in my HTML Like following. When I change options, I need to set the selected option color to `dark red` **if I select "success"**. Otherwise option color is default. I setup a jQuery for this.

HTML:

```
<select class="ready-list">
  <option value="failed">Failed</option>
  <option value="completed">Completed</option>
  <option value="success">Success</option>
  <option value="droped">Droped</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.ready-list').on('change', function() {
   var selected_v = this.value;
   if (selected_v != "success") {
      $(this).css("color", "#a94442");
   }
   else {
      $(this).css("color", "black");
   }
});
```

when I select an option except "success", the option will appear in `dark red`. But **when I click on the drop down list again, all the options are in dark red**. I tried to reset the options color to default by `on("click")` event when clicking again on the drop down but seems not working. How can I change the color only the appearing option?

Here is an example what I currently have

http://jsfiddle.net/m1vpzjyq/1/

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing this in a change handler instead of just styling the options with css.

Comment: @zfrisch Thank you. I edited

Comment: @James The dropdown is coming from back end and there could be many of drop downs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the context of `$(this)`.

In this case, `$(this)` is `$('.ready-list')`... The `<select>` element. And, if I understand correctly, you want the selected `<option>` to change color based on it's value.

If you apply a color to an element... It also applies to the childs. So you have to also define something for them.

And I think you misused the operator in the value comarison. `!=` should be `==` to set red if "success" is selected.

> I need to set the selected option color to dark red if I select "success".

```js
$('.ready-list').on('change', function() {
  var selected_v = this.value;
  $(this).find("option").css("color", "black");  // Set all options to black.
  $(this).css("color", "black");  // Set the select color to black.
  if (selected_v == "success") {
    $(this).find("option:selected").css("color", "#a94442");  // Set selected to red.
    $(this).css("color", "#a94442");  // Set the select color to red.
  }
  /*  This part is now useless...
  else {
    $(this).css("color", "black");
  }*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="ready-list">
  <option value="failed">Failed</option>
  <option value="completed">Completed</option>
  <option value="success">Success</option>
  <option value="droped">Droped</option>
</select>
```

---

**Edit**

Here is a shorter JS version for the same result... Using 2 CSS rules and a class.

```js
$('.ready-list').on('change', function() {
  (this.value == "success") ?
    $(this).addClass("success-selected") : $(this).removeClass("success-selected")
});
```

```css
/* To apply the dark red color to the <select> elements */
.success-selected{
  color:#a94442;
}
/* For the options that should remain black */
.success-selected>option:not(:checked){
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="ready-list">
  <option value="failed">Failed</option>
  <option value="completed">Completed</option>
  <option value="success">Success</option>
  <option value="droped">Droped</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point of the event handler so I would just style the options with css

```css
.ready-list option {
  color: #a94442;
}
.ready-list option[value='success'] {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select class="ready-list">
  <option value="failed">Failed</option>
  <option value="completed">Completed</option>
  <option value="success">Success</option>
  <option value="droped">Droped</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code will solve your problem,

```
 $('.ready-list').on('change', function() {
    var selected_v = $('.ready-list').find(":selected");
    $(selected_v).siblings().css("color", "black");   
    if (selected_v.text() != "Success") {
    $(selected_v).css("color", "#a94442");
    }
   });
```